# ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this error message when a google bot tries to visit one of my controllers.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template channels/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:"sv-SE", :en], :formats=>["*/*;q=0.9"], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/opt/www/app/releases/20120228181534/app/views" * "/opt/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views"
```

The problem is that I can't reproduce it.
The error has occurred 121 times the last week (according to [airbrake](http://airbrake.io/pages/home)).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/a8e12e0f5a00676d49e0) is the backtrace.

Row 18, which is the only row mentioned that exists in my app, is the `super` part of this code

```
def render(options = {}, extra_options = {}, &block)
  if request.headers['X-PJAX'] or params[:no_layout] == "true" or params[:_pjax] 
    options[:layout] = false
  end
  super(options, extra_options, &block)
end
```

The controller method `channels#show` looks like this

```
def show
  @channel   = # ...
  @today     = # ...
  @yesterday = # ...
  @tomorrow  = # ...
end
```

Visiting the url that raised the error for the google bot doesn't raise an error for me.

The only urls that fails is the one that contains special char like `{"action"=>"show", "id"=>"25-jönköping", "controller"=>"channels"}`. The `ORIGINAL_FULLPATH` value is set to `/channels/25-j%c3%b6nk%c3%b6ping`.

I'm using rails 3.2.1.

Comment: Which URL is it hitting? Try going to that URL yourself in development. Also, check the HTTP referrer to see what page it's coming from.

Comment: @nicholaides I've already tried to visit the url in question, which works.

Comment: What's the live URL for this application?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this error as well on a Rails 3 app and have been in same boat about replicating the error. The log has the Missing Template error, but when I manually try the request, it works fine.

I suspect that the HTTP request from Google is not setting a mime that Rails is processing correctly. The crude solution I found is to remove the view template mime, so

```
example/index.html.erb
```

is now

```
example/index.erb
```

This stops the Missing Template error, since the template will be used for all mimes.

Comment: You saved me hours!

Answer (score 3):

This has been recently fixed in master and back-ported to 3.2 branch:
See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/736 for the original bug report, https://gist.github.com/1754727 for monkey patches and github.com/rails/rails/pull/4918 for accepted pull request.